# How to display a single property of an object in listview

Tags: flutter

I have a list of goal objects with two properties, description (what I want to display) and ID (used as a key to identify it). Ultimately I want a list of goal descriptions (ex. mow lawn, get groceries etc) but I'm confused how to specify a single property with the listview builder. The reason I'm using an object is because I want to use swipe to dismiss on the list. I'm using an object to give each goal a unique key, therefore when I swipe to dismiss I can safely undo the dismissal / reorder the list.

File Structure: lib folder contains functions, goals and main. A sub-folder in the lib folder called UI contains form and home.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:aurelius/UI/home.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "ToDo", 
      home: myWidgets(),
    );
  }
}

Widget myWidgets(){
  return GoalsList();
}
```

**home.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:aurelius/goals.dart';
import 'package:aurelius/functions.dart';

//Goals List Variables
var goals = List<Goals>();

final TextEditingController listCtrl = new TextEditingController();

class GoalsList extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _GoalsListState createState() => _GoalsListState();
}

class _GoalsListState extends State<GoalsList>{

  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(); //key for goal form

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    final listSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1;

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      extendBody: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,

      //Navigation Bar 
      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
          ),
          child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          elevation: 4.0,
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
          label: const Text('Add Goal'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          splashColor: Colors.white,

          //Pop-up Dialogue
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context){
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Center(child: new Text("New Goal:",)),
                  content: Form(
                    key: formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
                          ),
                          controller: listCtrl, 

                        ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        child: Text("ADD"),
                        onPressed: (){
                          goals.add(createGoal(listCtrl.text));
                          listCtrl.clear();
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },        
                        splashColor: Colors.blue,
                        elevation: 2,
                        )
                      ]
                    ),
                  )
                );
              }
            );
          },
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation:FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,

      //Bottom App Bar
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: -30.0,
        color: Colors.black,
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, 
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),color: Colors.white,splashColor: Colors.white, onPressed: (){},),
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.settings),color: Colors.white,splashColor: Colors.white, onPressed: (){},),
          ],
        ),
      ),

      //Goals List Box
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: listSize,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: goals.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
            return Dismissible(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              //Green background and icon for left side swipe
              background: Container(
                color: Colors.green[300],
                 padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.check_box,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              //Green background and icon for right side swipe
              secondaryBackground: Container(
              color: Colors.green[300],
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.check_box,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              onDismissed:(direction){
                if(goals.contains(index)){
                  setState((){
                    goals.removeAt(index);
                  });
                }
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(goals[index].description),
                ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        ),

        //Potential more rows here

        ],
      )
    );
  }
}

}
```

**goals.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:aurelius/UI/home.dart';

class Goals{
  String description; //part visible to user 
  int id;

  Goals({this.description,this.id});
}
```

**functions.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:aurelius/goals.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

createGoal(String text){
  var goal = new Goals();
  goal.description = text;
  goal.id = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  return goal;
}
```

**form.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AddButtonState createState() => new AddButtonState();
}

class AddButtonState extends State<AddButton>{
  Color addbuttoncolor = Colors.red;
  IconData addIcon = Icons.add;

  void onPressed(){
    setState((){
      if (addIcon == Icons.add) {
            addIcon = Icons.clear;
      }
      else{
      addIcon = Icons.add;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
             new RawMaterialButton(
                onPressed: onPressed,
                child: new Icon(
                  addIcon,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  size: 35.0,
                ),
                shape: new CircleBorder(),
                elevation: 2.0,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              ),
            ]
        ),
      ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the whole ListView.builder( ) code? What issue you are getting now?

Comment: sure I added the whole code and the issue I'm having is when I add items they display as null. (removed inside of container code from the item builder because its  purely decoration left the important code).

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is when you creating the goal, you don't return created goal. Your createGoal() method should return the goal like below:

```
createGoal(String text){
  var goal = new Goals();
  goal.description = text;
  goal.id = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  return goal; // Add this 
}
```

Comment: I've added this and at the bottom of my builder code I've changed it to "Text(goals[index].description)," so that it only displays the property but now I'm getting an error "the getter 'id' was called null".

Comment: What happen when you remove this line:  key: ObjectKey(goals[index].id)? Do you get error with "description"?

Comment: If I completely remove it I get "key != null is not true". I tried changing it to "key: UniqueKey()" which gives me no errors but nothing is displaying when I add to the list.

Comment: 2 things: 1. I don't understand why you need this, is it for dismissing the dialog Navigator.pop(context);?  2. I don't see you call setState() anywhere to update the list after you added?

Comment: I believe the builder handles any changes detected so it updates when I add something to the list. I had it working prior with a list of strings rather than objects. The user swipes the item that is displayed to delete it and the key is used to identify which item it was. Reference: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/dismissible

Comment: If you can share the whole widget code, I will try it on my side

Comment: Sure thing give me a moment I'll edit the post to include the whole code

Comment: Give me sometime. I will check it!

Comment: No worries and thanks again I greatly appreciate it

Comment: I added text color to the code and it works: Text(goals[index].description, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),). But I found many things you can improve in your code. If you want to talk more, you can add my Skype id: huyphuc_tn

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see is that you don't return the object you create in createGoal().

To display the description with the Dismissible, you would just set its child to `child: Text(goals[index].description)`

To optimize the code, you can initialize the Goal id directly in the class itself. You can set the constructor as `Goals(this.description)` and the createGoal function will not be needed anymore.

*PS: Keeping your class names singular is a better practice*

Comment: You're right good catch I forgot to return the object in createGoal(). To display the description when you mentioned using child is this within the list builder?

Comment: It is in the builder, I was talking about the Dismissible's child. I edited for clarity.

Comment: I've changed it to (edited it in my original post as well) "Text(goals[index].description)," so that it only displays the property but now I'm getting an error "the getter 'id' was called null".

Comment: In your Goal class : `int id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;`